# Does the battery grip for the Canon 1000D fit on the Canon EOS T3/1100D?

Tags: canon, battery-grip, canon-1100d

Is the battery grip for 1000D(BG-E5) a direct fit on 1100D ? I was searching for aftermarket and Canon brand ones but they mention that its suitable for 1000D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No the Canon BG-E5 is not officially compatible with the 1100D. Canon have not released a battery grip for the 1100D, neither does it appear they are planning to, since the SD card slot is inside the battery compartment you'd have to remove the grip every time you changed memory cards.

This appears to be another "feature" that is deliberately missing from this line in order to separate it from the xxxD line.

There seem to be a few third party grips produced but I'd worry about the quality. However a much better option if you're thinking of upgrading is the T1i (500d), which **is** compatible with the BG-E5!

Comment: I am not planning to upgrade now , so is there no other alternative ? I dont mind memory card getting jailed, as I plan on buying a bigger storage capacity card soon, if thats the case will BG-E5 fit on 1100D ?

Comment: @2-Stroker It's not officially supported, I would be very surprised if it did work, even if it fits since Canon seem to have intentionally disabled the battery grip option. There are third party grips which report to be compatible with the 1100D but I can't say if they're any good at all.

Comment: Was just checking out this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdpM1VuCmSA) and BG-E5 has connectors near the battery terminals which are not there in 1100D, so looks like if I want to use a Battery Grip I would have to use an aftermarket one for which I need to connect a wire from the outside and it will look odd and get in the way. Till canon releases one I am better off carrying extra battery in my camera bag !